# ufw rule to allow address on the same subnet?

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, ufw

I have a server running Linux hosting a website. It uses ufw as a firewall. I have ports 80 and 443 open to external traffic. This all works.

Now what I want to do is allow any traffic from my laptop on the same subnet so that I can connect via SSH and administer MySQL from my laptop on the LAN.

I have added a rule in ufw to allow everything from my laptop (192.168.1.10) to the server (192.168.1.20). This should allow my laptop to connect via port 22 so that I can use SSH...but it doesn't.

If I turn ufw off I can connect so this IS a firewall issue not a connectivity or SSH server issue.

If I re-enable ufw the allow traffic on port 22 from ANYWHERE, I can connect from my laptop.

I've tried allowing port 22 from just my laptop.

What am I doing wrong? How do I "lock" port 22 down so that only my laptop can access it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you reach your server from the local network? Through a switch or through a router/NAT … Trace your connection to know … Your server might see the connection from your laptop as from a different source than what you assume.

Comment: Thanks Raffa. It's just using a normal broadband "router" so a combined router and switch. I would have thought the laptop and server would communicate straight across the switch as they are on the same subnet. You might be on to something though....